# Set redirect URLs to b2clogin.com gives the endpoint_resolution_error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

At B2C sign in we must set redirect URLs to b2clogin.com for Azure Active Directory B2C

I've checked this page: 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin.md

I have separate application for frontend and backend part.

I have this configurations on the frontend side:

```
getB2CMaslConfig(){
    return {
        clientID: 'clienId',           
        authority: "https://tenantName.b2clogin.com/tfp/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/policyNAme/v2.0/",            
        scopes: ["https://tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/api/read"],
        validateAuthority: false
    };
```

I have this config in the backend side:

```
<add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://tenantName.b2clogin.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1}" />   
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="tenantName.onmicrosoft.com" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="clientId" />
<add key="ida:SignUpSignInPolicyId" value="policyNAme" />

<!-- The following settings is used for requesting access tokens -->
<add key="api:ReadScope" value="read" />
<add key="api:WriteScope" value="write" />
},
```

If I use the login.microsoftonline.com instead of tenantName.b2clogin.com everything works fine, but if I change to tenantName.b2clogin.com I keep getting the error: "endpoints_resolution_error:Endpoints cannot be resolved"

Can you please advise how to change the redirect URLs in order to work well?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it failing on the frontend side or the backend side (or both)?

Comment: it's failing on the frontend part

Comment: @ChrisPadgett do you have any idea why it is failing?

Comment: @Kar are you using MSAL .NET for authentication?